# How to create "Theme Apps" for iPhone (3G, 3GS, 4S) Using xcode without jailbraking?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I need to develop one application for iPhone which is named as "Theme Apps"

My requirement is like this :

> This is a simple iPhone App that allows the user to press the "app
>   icon" and the iPhone Theme immediately changes the entire theme.
>
> By pressing this button inside the app... the Theme of the iPhone will
>   switch between "normal" and "special mode"
>
> In "special mode", anything that can be changed to a specific color
>   (just one color) will change. This needs to be done without
>   jailbreaking the phone and needs to serve as an "on/off" switch type
>   of functionality.

---

I searched everywhere but not got anything about it whether it is possible in iPhone or not OR how to do it in iPhone....

Please tell me how to do it or provide any link which can help me for the same.

Comment: If I wanted this - I'd use an Android phone.

Comment: You can't do this in iOS using legal APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Apple lets you play with the OS of the phone. If you find a way to do it, it'll most likely be rejected on the app store, just a heads up.